# How to save the results produced by Chrome DevTools' queryObjects()

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Chrome DevTools has a console feature called queryObjects that lets you find all the objects with a particular constructor; e.g.

```
queryObjects(Promise)
```

However, it seems to only display the objects, not return them. This means that I can't write, say,

```
queryObjects(MyCustomType)[4].getName()
```

Is there a way to do this?

I am using Chrome 67.0.3396.87

Comment: No way. It invokes console API [internally](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/devtools/front_end/sdk/ConsoleModel.js?l=246). Actually it's pretty weird why they decided to implement it this way. Consider posting a feature request on https://crbug.com - note, if they implement it, it'll be via .then()

Comment: I guess it was made this way to discourage usage of the api in production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've run the queryObjects(MyCustomType) command you can right-click on the resulting Array(XX) in the console and select "Store As Global Variable". It'd be better if you could just do `let myThings = queryObjects(MyCustomType);`.